# How do I access my Windows partition using the command line?

Tags: command-line, windows, filesystem, mount, ntfs

I had a problem with my Ubuntu install, and I need to uninstall it. However, I have one folder on there with an important assignment in it that I'd like to keep still. I can still get into Ubuntu with the command line, and it was installed beside Windows so I had access to my Windows partition as well. My question is - is it possible to access the Windows partition using the command line?

Comment: If you are not comfortable with commandline-fu, you should be able to boot from a LiveCD/LiveUSB and copy the files using the GUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to know the partition your Windows is. For that you can use the command

```
cat /proc/partitions
```

Then you need to make a folder, where the partition will be mounted to:

```
mkdir /mnt/win
```

Next

```
mount /dev/*** /mnt/win
```

Then

```
cd /mnt/win
```

Comment: If the windows partition was labelled, you can also use `/dev/disk/by-label/*` instead of `/dev/sdXY`. (use `ls -lA /dev/disk/by-label` to get a list or use tab-completion on `/dev/disk/by-label/`)

Comment: `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` (or `sdb` ... etc. for you second drive) is really more useful than `cat /proc/partitions`.