# Seeing Windows files from Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: 11.04, windows-7, macbook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I access my Windows partition using the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25466/how-do-i-access-my-windows-partition-using-the-command-line)

I have Ubuntu 11.04 on Windows 7, both sit on Macbook Pro 13, 5,5. Is it possible to 'see' Windows files?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, nothing is needed in your end in order to see them. You can also make windows partitions automount at login using ntfs-config (it can be found in software center)

Comment: Thanks very much. Complicated for a novice like me but I get the gist.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I clearly understood your question... nevertheless if you want to "see" your windows files from within ubuntu you can do it either by:

1. Clicking the disk device which should show in nautilus like [this](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/Rjtm-plZh9-B-0Wql-T-Bw?feat=directlink) or...
2. Adding the device to "fstab" which is the Unix configuration file for filesystems/partitions/disks
3. Using ntfs-config

If you'd like to go with the second option than execute this command either from the terminal or pressing "Alt + F2":

```
gksu gedit /etc/fstab
```

Then you'll see several lines, add one at the end of the file like this:

```
/dev/sda2   /media/Windows7_OS  ntfs-3g defaults,user,locale=en_US.utf8 0 0
```

You'll need only to change the first and second options, the first (/dev/sda2) is the partition that contains your windows files, the second is the "mount point" which is the folder that will show you those files. So change accordingly, if your disk is an S-ATA disk then it will be a "sd", the letter represents the order of the disk and the number the partition like so:

```
/dev/sda -> primary master
/dev/sdb -> primary slave
/dev/sdc -> secondary master
/dev/sdd -> secondary slave
```

And if you have a laptop you will have only one disk for sure, so most probable you will have something like this:

```
/dev/sda1 -> Primary partition on first hard disk
/dev/sda2 -> Secondary partition on first hard disk
/dev/sda3 -> Third partition on first hard disk
etc...
```

So if you have windows installed on your second partition (first partition should be the OSX probably) you may need to use /dev/sda3 since windows installs a hidden partition for boot since vista which would be /dev/sda2

Save the file and close it. Then you need to make the folder where the filesystem will be mounted if it doesnt exist already, I like to have mine under /media which is the default folder that ubuntu uses (and so other several linux distros) to mount removable media for example, open up a terminal from the dash or press "Alt + Ctrl + T" and type this:

```
sudo mkdir /media/Windows7_OS
```

Change Windows7_OS to whatever you like, just make sure that this path is the same you added in your fstab.

If you find the above too hard you can always just install "[ntfs-config](http://flomertens.free.fr/ntfs-config/)" either from the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-config
```

Or from the software center, search for that package.

Once you install the tool is pretty self explanatory how to use it. I'd post an image but since my reputation is so low it is marked as spam :P

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well that IS a difficult answer... You could just tell him YES and how. And now you give a solution nobody understands. Even when I know how Ubuntu works, I got scared of that :D